# How can I get a breadcrumbs array form a query (in Laravel)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, breadcrumbs

I have a **database table "documents"** with this structure:

```
// table documents:
|id|parent_id|name       |
|1 |0        |foldername1|
|2 |0        |foldername2|
|2 |1        |subfolder  |
```

In my Laravel Model **Document.php** I have this method:

```
 public function parent()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo($this, 'parent_id', 'id');
 }
```

But how can I get an *array* with my breadcrumbs in my controller?

I've tried many things, but it's not working... :(

**DocumentController.php:**

```
// NOT WORKING EXAMPLE!!
public function index()
{
    $file = Document::findOrFail(2);

    if ($file->parent) {
         $breadcrumbs[] = $this->setBreadcrumbs($file->parent);
    }
    dd($breadcrumbs);

}

private function setBreadcrumbs(Document $file)
{
    $arr = [];
    if ($file->parent) {
        $arr[] = $this->setBreadcrumbs($file->parent);
    } else {
        return $arr;
    }
    return $file->id;
}
```

Comment: Why is `setBreadCrumbs ()` called recursively? You can test out getting $file-> parent and see if you even have any result in the first place

Comment: Yes, $file->parent returns the right parent value. But how can I run $file->parent in a recursively way in my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just having a breadcrumbs attribute on the model?

```
class File {

    public function getBreadcrumbsAttribute()
    {
        if($this->parent){
            return array_merge($this->parent->breadcrumbs, [$this->id]);
        }
        return [$this->id];
    }
}
```

Then you can just call `$file->breadcrumbs`.  This could be easily adapted if you need to pass filenames or links to the array instead.

Comment: Thanks very much! This is exacly what i need!

Comment: A little question... How can I get the ids as key in my array?
I have tried: 
return array_merge($this->parent->breadcrumbs, [$this->id => $this->original_name]) and: 
return [$this->id => $this->original_name];
But my keys are still 0, 1, 2, etc.

Comment: If you use numerical keys you might lose the ordering you need to properly display breadcrumbs.  If you need that I would replace `[$this->id]` with `['id'=>$this->id,'name'=>$this->original_name]` so you have a properly ordered array with both the IDs and names available.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your help!